Flutter: RangeError (offset): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2374: 2496
When I try to build my app in release mode I run:
flutter build apk --release    

And I get the following error:
RangeError (offset): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2374: 2496

The app works fine in debug mode.
I found a github issue where they said that updating flutter to the latest beta version solved it, but I ran:
flutter channel beta

And
flutter upgrade

And still get the error.
I opened an issue there but havent had an answer yet.
I expect to be able to generate the app bundle for uploading to google play.
This is the log:

RangeError (offset): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2374:
2496 #0      RangeError.checkValueInInterval
(dart:core/errors.dart:313) #1      Source.getLocation
(package:kernel/ast.dart:14992) #2      Component.getLocation
(package:kernel/ast.dart:14787) #3      _getLocationInComponent
(package:kernel/ast.dart:15181) #4
Procedure._getLocationInEnclosingFile (package:kernel/ast.dart:3329)
#5      TreeNode._getLocationInEnclosingFile (package:kernel/ast.dart:207) #6
TreeNode._getLocationInEnclosingFile (package:kernel/ast.dart:207) #7
TreeNode._getLocationInEnclosingFile (package:kernel/ast.dart:207) #8
TreeNode._getLocationInEnclosingFile (package:kernel/ast.dart:207) #9
TreeNode._getLocationInEnclosingFile (package:kernel/ast.dart:207)
#10     TreeNode.location (package:kernel/ast.dart:203) #11     localFunctionName
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/utils.dart:449) #12
SummaryCollector.createSummary
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/summary_collector.dart:630) #13
TypeFlowAnalysis.getSummary
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1782) #14
_DirectInvocation._processFunction
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:398) #15
_DirectInvocation.process
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:287) #16
_WorkList.processInvocation
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1663) #17
_WorkList.process
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1606) #18
TypeFlowAnalysis.process
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/analysis.dart:1811) #19
transformComponent
(package:vm/transformations/type_flow/transformer.dart:121) #20
runGlobalTransformations (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:589) #21
compileToKernel (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:489) <asynchronous
suspension> #22     FrontendCompiler.compile
(package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:639) <asynchronous
suspension> #23     starter
(package:frontend_server/starter.dart:101) <asynchronous suspension>
#24     main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13)
<asynchronous suspension>

And this is the output of flutter doctor:

[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.22.0-0.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows
[Versi¢n 10.0.19045.4291], locale es-CO) • Flutter version
3.22.0-0.3.pre on channel beta at C:\src\flutter • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git • Framework revision
87b652410d (3 weeks ago), 2024-04-23 21:41:18 -0500 • Engine revision
b4bfd45986 • Dart version 3.4.0 (build 3.4.0-282.3.beta) • DevTools
version 2.34.3
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or
higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
version 34.0.0) • Android SDK at
C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk • Platform
android-34-ext8, build-tools 34.0.0 • Java binary at: C:\Program
Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java • Java version OpenJDK
Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231) • All Android
licenses accepted.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web • Chrome at C:\Program
Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community
2022 17.9.4) • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Community • Visual Studio Community 2022 version
17.9.34714.143 • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3) • Android Studio at C:\Program
Files\Android\Android Studio • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter • Dart plugin can be
installed from: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart • Java
version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
[√] VS Code (version 1.89.1) • VS Code at
C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code •
Flutter extension version 3.88.0
[√] Connected device (4 available) • SM A226BR (mobile) •
R9WW201HDLA • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) • Windows (desktop)
• windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n
10.0.19045.4291] • Chrome (web)       • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 124.0.6367.202 • Edge (web)         • edge        •
web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 124.0.2478.105
[√] Network resources • All expected network resources are
available.
• No issues found!


I solved the issue by switching to the master channel, not the beta.
With:
flutter channel master
Version 3.22.0-36.0.pre.48

It works! Thanks you save my day.
I switched to 3.23.0 candidate and I solved the problem too, in general, it's a problem related to 3.22.2 into the stable channel.

I get it on 3.22.2
RangeError (offset): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1998: 2276
#0      RangeError.checkValueInInterval (dart:core/errors.dart:313)
#1      Source.getLocation (package:kernel/ast.dart:14992)
#2      Component.getLocation (package:kernel/ast.dart:14787)

how did you solve? , I have 3.22.0 and I have the same
